# How do I concatenate these strings?

Tags: variables, string-manipulation, execute

I have two string variables:

```
let url = "https://URL/path/to/repo"
let branch = "GIT-HASH"
```

I want to concatentate them and echo it on the shell:

```
let result = url . branch
exec '!echo '.result
```

I only ever see `url` in the output, and never `branch`. I can echo `branch` by itself and that works, I can put `branch` before `url`, but `url . branch` does not work. Is vimscript trying to evaluate the url as a substitute command? I'm not sure why this isn't working.

Vim version is compiled from `v8.2.4236`

Comment: Do you have a complete example that can be copy/pasted and run to reproduce the issue? What you've posted seems fine to me (other than the missing slash in the `result` variable, but that's not really what the question is about).